# SQL Server 2008 R2 login simply doesn't work

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I've been unsuccessfully try to make this work for days now. I've tried dozens of suggestions in posts with the exact same result.

80040ed4 Failed login for user 'myuser'

Please if you have a link to a tutorial with screen shots that doesn't leave out some crucial step, post it here.

If you know how to do this from step 1 to final, please reply.

SBS 2008 R2 is the version

I simply want to create a user that can read data from a database named 'SharedWebDb' that is located on MYSQLSERVER/SHAREPOINT

Thanks.

Comment: Found it finally. It was the authentication setting. Everything else is useless before that is changed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

To change security authentication mode

1. In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties.

2. On the Security page, under Server authentication, select the new server authentication mode, and then click OK.

3. In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to acknowledge the requirement to restart SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create a new login with sql server authentication.
Step 2: In server Role tab make him sysadmin.
Step 3: In user mapping tab choose you database,master,tempdb etc and marked it as dbowner
Step 4: Click on ok button.
Step 5: Right click on server name  and choose properties then in securities tab opt sql server and window Authentication mode and click on ok button.
Step 6: Restart you sql server.
Step 7: Now new sql server login will work :)